# Downloading QtDesigner for PyQt6 and converting .ui file to .py file with pyuic6

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyqt6

How do I download QtDesigner for PyQt6? If there's no QtDesigner for PyQt6, I can also use QtDesigner of PyQt5, but how do I convert this .ui file to .py file which uses PyQt6 library instead of PyQt5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install QtCreator or use command line `pyuic6 -o main.py main.ui`

Answer (score 10):

As they point out you can use pyuic6:

```
pyuic6 -o output.py -x input.ui
```

but in some cases there are problems in that the command is not found in the CMD/console, so the command can be used through python:

```
python -m PyQt6.uic.pyuic -o output.py -x input.ui
```